# Call 2 functions one after the other using AngularJS and Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In an ASP.NET MVC with WebApi using AngularJS.

I have this situation :

1. From the menu, I call an MVC action
2. I render a view. In this view I include the .js file with angularJS code, in the code I defined a function. I call this function directly after definition.
3. With the data returned I create
4. I apply DataTable (datatables.net) to generate the grid.

From point 1 to 3 no problem, I get the correct behavior.

The problem is I apply the datatable function before I get the datas. How can I solve this ?

Is there a way to call the code marked has "XXXXX" below when the function 'loadMyData'

The view look like :

```
@section scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/MyScriptsBinding/SampleIndexViewModel.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}

<div data-ng-controller="SampleIndexViewModel">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="sample_1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="item in itemList">
            <tr style="vertical-align: central">
                <td>{{ item.Field1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Field2 }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

SampleIndexViewModel.js :

```
appMainModule.controller("SampleIndexViewModel", function ($scope, $http, viewModelHelper) {
    $scope.itemList = [];
    $scope.loadMyData = function () {
        viewModelHelper.apiGet('api/mytest/list', null,
            function (result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                    $scope.customers = result.data;
                }
            });
    }

    $scope.applyTable = function () {
        $('#sample_1').DataTable();
    }
    $scope.loadMyData();
    $scope.applyTable(); // XXXXX
});
```

Comment: one note , you are using   `ng-repeat` on  `tbody` and that causes the `tbody` to be repeated instead of just the row . Are you sure you want to repeat the whole `tbody` for each row ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try like below

Please change the code

```
$scope.applyTable();
```

Instead of using above code please use the below one.

```
 setTimeout(function () {
         $scope.applyTable();
    }, 300);
```

Comment: I tried, I can see the datable apply on the table and the datas coming after.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `applyTable` function inside `loadMyData` function.

```
$scope.applyTable = function () {
        $('#sample_1').DataTable();
    }

$scope.loadMyData = function () {
        viewModelHelper.apiGet('api/mytest/list', null,
            function (result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                    $scope.customers = result.data;
                }
                $scope.applyTable(); 
            });
    } 

$scope.loadMyData();
```

Comment: then you should mention that problem in your question

Answer (score 0):

With the $http service, you can use a promise to execute a piece of code after a successful http call. See this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Specifically, you'd want to do something like this:

```
$scope.itemList = [];

$scope.applyTable = function () {
  $('#sample_1').DataTable();
}

$http.get('api/mytest/list').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.customers = data;
    $scope.applyTable();
  })
```

Of course, this is assuming that you have your datatable set up properly. Also, your `for` loop doesn't really make any sense. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with it?

I'd recommend using the angular-datatables module (http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) as it adds a helpful Angular layer on top of jQuery datatables.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how `viewModelHelper.apiGet` is implemented, but if it was returning a promise you could simply do:

```
$scope.loadMyData = function () {
    return viewModelHelper.apiGet('api/mytest/list').then(function (result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                $scope.customers = result.data;
            }
    });
}

$scope.applyTable = function () {
    $('#sample_1').DataTable();
}

$scope.loadMyData().then($scope.applyTable);
```

If it's not returning a promise you could always make `loadMyData` do so by using the `$q` service:

```
$scope.loadMyData = function () {
    return $q(function(resolve){
            viewModelHelper.apiGet('api/mytest/list', null, 
                function (result) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                        $scope.customers = result.data;
                    }
                    resolve();
                }
            );
        });
}
```

And then you just chain the calls:

`$scope.loadMyData().then($scope.applyTable);`